# How to Reheat Beef Tenderloin?

Tags: beef, reheating

I have a Tenderloin that was roasted to medium and seared. How can I best reheat it without it getting dry and tough?

Comment: Don't reheat it, slice it thin, and serve on good bread with mayo & horseradish = an awesome roast beef sandwich.

Comment: +1 agreed, taking a good peice of beef past medium is almost a sin so don't re-heat, look for options, sandwich is a good start. Slicing into a salad could be done, or even slice it super thin and wrap it around some cooked and dressed asperagus.

Comment: @boxed-dinners: Taking it TO medium is a sin. Tenderloin should moo when you cut into it.

Answer (score 4):

Bring it back to the old school, which is place a covered plate in a 125-200 degree oven until just warmed through.  It was the option of choice pre microwave, and still the best way for roasts and pastas IMO. It should come out steaming after about 20 minutes, depending on temp.  You lose less moisture the lower you go, but it takes longer so you get to choose the median point between those that's good for you.

Comment: This is almost exactly my method.  Our beef is definitely more on the rare side, though.

Comment: why covered? keep moisture in? 

I don't have any oven proof plates, so going to use a pan and monitor carefully with a instant-read thermometer.. will probably re-sear after

Answer (score 2):

It's probably too late for this particular instance, but something to keep in mind for the future.  If you make/eat a lot of roasted meats, such as tenderloin, prime rib, pulled pork, etc., you would be wise to invest in a Foodsaver.  Divide your leftovers into single-size portions, seal them in vacuum bags, and freeze them.  When it's time to reheat, just drop a bag into boiling water and reheat.  You will reheat your food without losing any moisture.